# Granularity of tasks in airflow

Tags: airflow

For one task, there are many helper tasks -  fetch/save properties from file/db, validations, audits. These helper methods are not time consuming.

One sample DAG flow,

```
fetch_data >> actual_processing >> validation >> save_data >> audit
```

What's the recommendation in this scenario:

- create one task for each helper task
- keep everything in one task?

What's the overhead of an airflow task assuming there are enough resources?

Comment: Always try to keep maximum stuff in single task (and preferably have tasks that run for several minutes than few seconds) to (not exhaustive list) **[1]** minimize [scheduling latency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63950467/how-can-one-create-somewhat-complex-airflow-branch-operators#comment113093795_63950467) **[2]** minimize load on `scheduler` / `webserver` / `SQLAlchemy` backend db.

Comment: Exception to this rule could be (not exhaustive list) **[1]** when idempotency dictates that you must break your tasks into smaller steps to prevent wasteful re-computation / breaking of workflow **[2]** peculiar cases such as if you are using `pool` to limit load on an external resource => in this case, each operation that touches that external resource has to be modelled as a separate task in order to enforce load-restriction via `pool`s

Comment: @y2k-shubham you should add these comments as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question-1**

> What's the recommendation in this scenario

Always try to keep maximum stuff in single task (and preferably have *fat* tasks that run for several minutes than *lean* tasks running for few seconds) to (not exhaustive list)

- **1.** minimize [scheduling latency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63950467/how-can-one-create-somewhat-complex-airflow-branch-operators#comment113093795_63950467)
- **2.** minimize load on `scheduler` / `webserver` / `SQLAlchemy` backend db.

---

Exception to this rule could be (not exhaustive list)

- **1.** when *idempotency* dictates that you must break your tasks into smaller steps to prevent wasteful re-computation / breaking of workflow as told in [Using Operators](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/operator/index.html) doc

> An operator represents a single, ideally idempotent, task

- **2.** peculiar cases such as if you are using [`pools`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html#pools) to limit load on an external resource => in this case, each operation that touches that external resource has to be modelled as a separate task in order to enforce load-restriction via `pool`s

---

**Question-2**

> What's the overhead of an airflow task assuming there are enough resources?

While I can't provide a technically precise answer here, do understand that Airflow's scheduler essentially works on a *poll-based approach*

- at every *heartbeat* (usually ~ 20-30 s), it scans meta-db and `DagBag` to determine the list of `task`s that are ready to run for e.g. like

  - a `scheduled` task who's upstream tasks have been run
  - an `up_for_retry` task who's `retry_delay` has expired

From the [old docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/1.10.1/scheduler.html#:%7E:text=The%20Airflow%20scheduler%20monitors%20all,whether%20they%20can%20be%20triggered.)

> The Airflow scheduler monitors all tasks and all DAGs, and triggers
> the task instances whose dependencies have been met. Behind the
> scenes, it monitors and stays in sync with a folder for all DAG
> objects it may contain, and periodically (every minute or so) inspects
> active tasks to see whether they can be triggered.

- this means that having more `task`s (as well as more *connections* / *dependencies* between them) will increase the workload of scheduler (more checks to be evaluated)

---

Suggested reads

- [Airflow scheduler is slow to schedule subsequent tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47450855/3679900)
- [When Airflow isn’t fast enough](https://medium.com/@manuelmourato25/when-airflow-isnt-fast-enough-distributed-orchestration-of-multiple-small-workloads-with-celery-afb3daebe611)
- [Use Airflow for frequent tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49676127/3679900)

> For all these issues with running a massive number of fast/small tasks
> , we require fast distributed task management, that does not require
> previous resource allocation (as Airflow does), as each ETL task needs
> very few resources, and allows tasks to be executed one after the
> other immediately.